# How to print the results of the Parameterized values in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, devops

I have a build with a parameter, also I have few dependencies from another project. I had to print the results of the parameters and save them in a specific folder. I used echo, but is there any other way or plugin

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to write parameters that were passed, out to a file in a folder. Here's an example using Groovy / Scripted pipeline

```
stage('Create and write output file') {
    f = new File("${WORKSPACE}/output_file.txt")
    f.append("SomeParameter = ${params.SomeParameter}"
}
```

Comment: If it is a freestyle project? not a pipeline project.